# Windows 10 thumbnail issues, Open With freezes, Apps & Features freezes, all at once

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 install is exhibiting a handful of abnormal behaviors that all occur at once and persist until a relog or restart. I haven't yet managed to nail down exactly what triggers the issues but it **seems to be related to viewing a large amount of thumbnails in a short period**. I don't usually encounter the issues unless I go out of my way to view many thumbnails, such as when editing and sorting photos.

**The three symptoms I have encountered so far:**

- Windows gives up generating thumbnails at all. Instead of even attempting to generate them (and getting an endless loading bar), folders load instantly with all thumbnails being the default 'empty paper' icon.
- Explorer (including the taskbar) freezes when attempting to open the 'Open With' context menu.
- The 'Apps & Features' app locks up on open and just shows an empty window.

These are all isolated issues and the rest of the OS behaves exceptionally with zero problems.

Even before these specific behaviors occur, **thumbnail generation is lackluster at best and seems to get worse** the more thumbnails you view and the longer Windows is running. Folders of images will be 50/50 thumbnails and the default JPG icon, all videos will just have the default video icon (VLC in my case), etc. The thumbnail cache is never more than 30 or 40 MB when these issues begin.

Open With freeze happens even on .txt files with only five entries in Open With: Notepad, Notepad++, WordPad, Search the Store, and Choose another app.

Fixes I've tried (unsuccessfully):

- Installing a third-party thumbnail manager (Icaros). Thumbnails still die like they did before.
- Clearing thumbnail cache and disabling SilentCleanup's thumbnail cache deletion via registry.
- Running CCleaner on the registry to remove obsolete 'Open With' entries.
- sfc /scannow

HW/SW Info:

- Windows 10 Home x64 10.0.17134.471
- System disk is a 500GB Samsung 860 EVO (with plenty of space left)
- Two HDDs also installed, in addition to two HDDs simple mirrored with Storage Spaces
- System and OS install is only a few months old

**Is there a specific cause for this issue, and is a fix available?** Or does anyone have any additional insight into this issue?

Comment: Ran into the same issue, and it's indeed a Windows internal bug. The Resource Monitor utility (comes with Windows 10) shows that Explorer.EXE indeed gets stuck, and it gets stuck on `C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache_idx.db`