# Windows 10 can't rebuild thumbnail cache and is freezing Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, images

I'm using Windows 10.

I recently installed [IrfanView 64-bit](https://www.irfanview.com/), and also cleared my thumbnail cache with [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/).

---

#### Problem

Now random `jpg` and `png` images have thumbnails and many do not, they are stuck with the IrfanView icon. Video, such as `mp4`,  thumbnails are also missing.

[image: irfanview icon]

Sometimes it shows white icons and my View pane is disabled.

[image: white icon]

[image: view pane]

---

In folders, Explorer shows a green loading bar that never finishes.

[image: loading]

---

Right clicking on an image with a thumbnail will pop up the context menu, but right clicking on images without thumbnails freezes Explorer.

---

The Settings Menu also constantly freezes when clicking on items.

[image: settings]

---

#### Fix Attempts

1. Tried uninstalling IrfanView and using the default Windows Photos app, but then no thumbnails will appear, and opening an image only freezes Explorer. Right clicking on any image also freezes Explorer.
2. It tried clearing and rebuilding the cache with Disk Cleanup and CMD.
   https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-thumbnail-cache-windows-10
3. Tried using this icon rebuilder and restarting the computer.
   https://www.thewindowsclub.com/icon-cache-rebuilder-for-windows-10
4. Ran `chkdsk` and `sfc /scannow`, it fixed a corrupted `mscormmc.dll` but did not solve the problem.
5. Restored old CCleaner registry backup.
6. Ran a virus scan with Eset which came up clean.
7. Checked the health status of my SDD which says no problems.

Nothing has fixed the issue.

Comment: If you use AutoRuns to load an absolutely minimal configuration does the behavior with the icons change?

Comment: @Ramhound I have not used AutoRuns before, I just downloaded it, how should I setup a minimum config?

Comment: AutoRuns lots all keys for programs that start automatically configure a minimum configuration

Comment: Have you tried the solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/393735/application-icons-are-gone/393742#393742)?

Comment: @Ramhound I used Autoruns to uncheck some of the program and restarted the computer but the thumbnails still do not display. I did the first step in that solution, but the problem looks deeper than icon cache, a lot of things are going wrong with Windows, Explorer freezing, Settings Window freezing, I think IrfanView has ruined it. Some of these freezing problems go away when I uninstall IrfanView, but it also creates new ones.

Comment: @Ramhound I found here someone else has had the same problem with IrfanView and Windows 7. https://irfanview-forum.de/showthread.php?t=6347

Comment: I have IrfanView 32-bit here on my Windows 10 machine and no issues. I do not use CCleaner. I think it is possible that CCleaner may have deleted some things it should not have. Try running a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Everything to start.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Save.
Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key. 
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: Also, before you start the above, uninstall IrfanView and then when complete try the 32-bit version

Comment: CCleaner should absolutely never be used.

Comment: @John Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: @John I found this post. https://superuser.com/q/1390564/740888 The Right Click `Open With` menu also freezes Explorer. The comment says it's an internal bug and Windows is getting stuck building `iconcache_idx.db`.

Comment: Hello.  I had a right-context issue on this machine of mine here about a year and a half ago. Repair Install worked for a while, but the Final Solution was to Repair Install and keep data only (and so Profile) but no Apps .  I had to reinstall my applications. but the payoff is that the machine works very well in all respects

Comment: @MattMcManis - Please do not take the suggested course of action of reinstalling Windows 10.  If you do that, not only does it make it impossible to answer this question, it's an excessive solution to a problem that can be solved.  I am not saying I know the answer today, but tomorrow somebody might, reinstalling Windows is an action that is complete overkill in a situation like this.

Comment: @Ramhound I will not reinstall just yet, I will wait a few days because I have to backup all my files and make notes of all my settings. maybe someone or I can find a solution by then. If I can't, I will have to reinstall.

Comment: @Ramhound I was not able to find a solution. I had to reinstall, the problems were getting worse. I could no longer cut and paste files. The folder's left sidebar would disappear and turn white. I believe the registry was corrupted.

Comment: @MattMcManis - Windows keeps a backup copy of the registry.  I would have attempted to use that, before a reinstall, had you asked about the nature of the additional problems I could have suggested that solution.

Comment: @Ramhound I had made registry backups with CCleaner before this happened but when I merged it, it did not fix it.

Comment: CCleaner should never be used.  As I said Windows keeps its own registry backups.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. When this happens the "COM Surrogate" process was taking up ~7% CPU usage and it wouldn't stop when trying to cancel the thumnail generation via the "X" on the loading bar in Explorer. It stopped the loading bar but not the process and weird things would happen in Explorer like suddenly missing icons and an empty sidebar. Killing "COM Surrogate" restores normal operation for some time. I used [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to identify which process had a description of "COM Surrogate". I checked its properties to find out what it is executing.

[image: ddlhost.exe]

I searched for the ProcessID/GUID in the registry and it was the thumbnail generation. I opened the lower pane in Process Explorer to check the handles and saw one file.

[image: file d:\videos]

It seems thumbnail generation got stuck on trying to generate a thumbnail for that video. After deleting the file I haven't had any problems since and thumbnails get generated without issues.

Comment: How to create a good image that improves the question:  Windows has an inbuilt hotkey (Win + Shift + S) which executes the Snipping Tool. Any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @somebadhat Thanks for improving my wording and keeping it more concise first off. I do think you removed some info that was rather relevant, though. Like the information about the problematic video file to get an idea why the thumbnail generation got stuck at it. It's not a general solution, you may not want to just delete the affected file. Shortening, yes, but removing the info completely? Also the short background info about the "COM Surrogate" process may help understanding at least the first step.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you mentioned the snipping tool? I know about it, although I'm usually just "Print-Screen"-ing and cutting it in Paint or GIMP. If it's about the quality, that's because I didn't save those screenshots but just sent them to a friend in a Facebook chat. And as I posted the answer a few weeks later, I could just resort to those downscaled images. Also, I did cut them with the intention of keeping all useful info, but I'm also fine with the images you embedded.

Comment: I agree with you your answer needs some improvement. You are welcome to improve your answer any way you see fit. "Process Explorer provides the fantastic functionality of an icon you can drag to a target window causing Process Explorer to select that item in the process list." would be a good place to start. Be brief, to the point, and if you had good images why didn't you use them?

Comment: I'm a bit confused now.^^ The images I mean where the ones I linked to in my answer, that you also used as a base and cut them even more to only the most relevant area.
And while you're right about that functionality, I didn't and couldn't use that in this case, as there was no window for that, just some background process.^^
I will add back some info maybe soon.

Comment: You are my hero!
Saved me from formatting, had this problem since 9 months

Answer (score 2):

This was exactly my problem.
For months.
But I fixed it, finally.
Turns out there was a .heic picture on my desktop - the picture type iphones use these days. But it did not show on the desktop, no thumbnail. It did show in explorer as a file, but I could not delete it, en explorer freezed on it.
Reghunter turned out to be able to delete it. I'm sure there are other programs that can do this.
(Re-)installed heic and heif programs in the windows store.
Somehow windows 10 lost the connection to .jpg files in this process. Fixed that with individual standard app settings.

And now no more green bar, superfast thumnailing, all problems fixed.